# Get array from a multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to grab the classes array based an id from the object. (and store it)

```
const objs = {
     "1":{
          "name":"Candice",
          "classes": [00029,00023,00032,000222],
          "id":0002918
     },
     "2":{
           "name":"Clark",
           "classes":[000219,00029,00219],
           "id":00032
         }
}

const objsKeys = Object.keys(objs);
const userClasses = objKeys.find(a => objs[a].id === this.state.userId).classes
console.log(userClasses);

// expect output
[00029,00023,00032,000222]

// but returns
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.userId`?

Comment: @TimoSta 1 or 2 . the object key (not id value). Its supposed to check if they match (both object key and state id)

Comment: Probably an integer? `===` compares value and type, so `1 === '1'` equals `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the property name using **[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method, and you are trying to get `classes` property of string and which is `undefined` . So you need to get the property value from object using the property name returned by **[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method.

```
const userClasses = objs[objKeys.find(a => objs[a].id === this.state.userId)].classes
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the key.
Try:

```
const objs = {
     "1":{
          "name":"Candice",
          "classes": [00029,00023,00032,000222],
          "id":0002918
     },
     "2":{
           "name":"Clark",
           "classes":[000219,00029,00219],
           "id":00032
         }
}

const objsKeys = Object.keys(objs);

//if you console.log the following, you get the property/key of 2:
console.log(objsKeys.find(a => objs[a].id === 00032))

// you need to use that property to get the object value
const userClasses = objs[objsKeys.find(a => objs[a].id === this.state.userId)].classes
console.log(userClasses);
```